# How can I import data from external server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I want to import data from external server in my GridPanel. I've tried with this code:

```
 Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
       { name: 'HasError', type: 'string' },
       { name: 'ErrorString', type: 'char' }
       ]
    });
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://.../GetActivities.aspx',
            method: 'POST',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
               root: 'Data'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true

    });
    store.load();
```

Now I load it in my GridPanel.

```
 xtype: "grid",
 border: false,
 store: store,
 viewConfig: { forceFit: true },
 flex: 1,
 columns: [
        { header: "Aktivit&#228;tsnummer", width: 125, dataIndex: 'HasError', sortable: true },
        { header: "Zweck", width: 175, dataIndex: 'ErrorString', sortable: true }
 ]
```

I've tried the same code with a json file on the same server and it works

Comment: can you post some code please. I can not find anything useful in the Inet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the security restrictions you need to make the web call on code behind.

You call your server with ajax, and on code behind you call and get the data from the other server using the `WebRequest` that asp.net provide.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(TheWebPageToRead);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of browser cross domain restriction. You cannot create ajax request to other domain then your web is. 

Only possible solution is using iframe, because this is element, which can host external content in your site.

Answer (score 0):

We have created what we called a `ReRouteHandler`, basically it sees the request come in to the local server and that gets mapped to the remote server via the config file matching the url using regular expressions, thus calling the data on the remote server from the local server and passing back to the request, works very well indeed and simple to implement.